# how to disable code analysis on visual studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

How do I turn off code analysis? In the c++ vcxproj project properties, I've tried unchecking **my_proj.vcxproj** -> **properties** -> **code analysis** -> **enable code analysis on build**. However, when I build with verbose logging, I can see code analysis in the build command.

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.x\bin\HostX64\x64\CL.exe"  /c /I<lots_of_include_paths> /Zi /JMC /nologo /W4 /WX /diagnostics:classic /sdl /MP3 /Od /D CODE_ANALYSIS ... /analyze /analyze:plugin"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.x\bin\HostX64\x64\localespc.dll" /analyze:plugin"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.x\bin\HostX64\x64\EspXEngine.dll"  ...  my_file.cpp`

Within this command there are 2 sections that start with "/analyze:plugin". One for **EspXEngine.dll** and one for **localespc.dll**.  localespc has been causing problem on some machines at work so I want to delete it from the build command. I suspect there is something in the vcxproj xml but I haven't found it yet.

I tried adding `/analyze- /analyze /analyze:plugin"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.x\bin\HostX64\x64\EspXEngine.dll" to additional properties.  This works but give new warnings on D9025.

[image: Enable Code Analysis on Build screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Missing from my original question was order of the XML in my .vcxproj.  I don't know how but my `<PropertyGroup...><RunCodeAnalysis>...` was near the bottom of the file.  Deleting the block and letting visual studio recreate it using the checkbox, placed it higher up in the XML.

Microsoft Documentation states that **Order Matters** in the vcxproj file which is defined here.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/vcxproj-file-structure?view=msvc-170#impact-of-incorrect-ordering